# Can $(1-10^{-x})^y$, where x and y > 0, be simplified?

Tags: statistics

I would like to know if it is possible to simplify the expression $(1-10^{-x})^y$ where $x$ and $y\gt0$. If yes, the simplified formula would be helpful.

I don't have the competence or the tools (e.g. Mathematica) to find out by myself.

The goal is to find out under which conditions of values $x$ and $y$ the result tends toward $0$ and how fast. A $3$D graphic might help to do so, but a formal expression might make it more clear.

Edit: I initially gave the formula $(1-10^{-x})^{-y}$ which was wrong. I apologize for this error.

Comment: It is $0$ when $x=0$ and $y>0$.  To approach $0$ while having both positive, you need $x \ll y$

Comment: @Henry x *and* y must be > 0. Regarding the second part of your comment, is it possible to derive a relation to determine for instance how smaller than y x should be so that the result would be < 0.001 or something like that ?

Comment: I have addressed this in my answer.  Very small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- $(1-10^{-x})^y=0$ when $x=0$ and $y>0$, but you want to consider $x>0$
- With $y$ fixed, you have $(1-10^{-x})^y\to 0$ as $x \to 0_+$
- $(1-10^{-x})^y\lt \varepsilon$ when $x < - \log_{10}(1 - \varepsilon^{1/y}) \approx \frac{1}{\log_e(10)}\varepsilon^{1/y}$

This can require $x$ to be very small relative to $y$: for example with $y=0.1$ and $\epsilon = 0.001$ then you would need $x < 4.3 \times 10^{-31}$, and it only gets worse with smaller $y$

Comment: Thank you. I understand that the given expression was still too complex.  In fact the expression should be $(1-p)^n$. This yields the probability that the event with probability p to occur once never occurs in n events. We can use this to determine the probability that life appeared exactly once in the universe. n is then the number of planets (many billions) and p the average probability that life appears spontaneously by random process on one planet. I wanted to see if we can derive a relation between n and p from this formula. Sorry about the $10^{-x}.

Comment: @chmike That might be worth a different question.  For a binomial random variable (you would be assuming $p$ remains constant and each of the $n$ attempts are independent) the probability of no successes is $(1-p)^n$, of exactly one success is $np(1-p)^{n-1}$ and of two or more is $1-(1+(n-1)p)(1-p)^{n-1}$.  For $p$ small and $n$ large, $(1-p)^n \approx e^{-np)$

Comment: thank you very much. Sorry for my confusing answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the following helps but...

\begin{eqnarray}
(1-10^{-x})^{-y} &= \left( 1-\frac{1}{10^x}\right)^{-y}\\
                 &=  \left(\frac{10^x-1}{10^x}\right)^{-y} \\
                 &= \left(\frac{10^x}{10^x -1}\right)^{y} 
\end{eqnarray}

EDIT

Given the extra comment below, edit as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
(1-10^{-x})^{y} &= \left( 1-\frac{1}{10^x}\right)^{y}\\
                 &=  \left(\frac{10^x-1}{10^x}\right)^{y} \\
                 &= \left(\frac{10^x}{10^x -1}\right)^{-y} 
\end{eqnarray}
Incorporating David's comment below you could write
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{10^x-1} \right)^{-y}$$

And assess limits thereafter.

Comment: ... and possibly continuing with $\left(\frac{10^x - 1 + 1}{10^x - 1}\right)^{y} = \left(1 + \frac{1}{10^x - 1}\right)^{y}$ to have only one term with $x$.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó Absolutely yes, good spot!

Comment: Thank you very much but I made a big error in my formula. I'm very sorry about that and I'll immediately fix it.

Comment: Hi @chmike see above.

Comment: I don't think that the current answer helps, as the OP's revised formula is in its simplest form I think, only the negative power term is to be turned into a fraction, but after that why change anything? I would remove this and ask for clarification what is to be simplified...

Comment: @DávidLaczkó I agree, but for completeness I wanted to address the edited change in the OP's formula.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó indeed. If the probability of occurrence of some event is $p = 10^{-x}$, the probability that it never occurs in $y$ events is $(1 - p)^y)$. I would like to know under which conditions in terms of $x$ and $y$ the resulting probability would be for instance smaller than 0.001. Obviously, it would be satisfied when y is "much bigger" than x. But is it possible to determine how much bigger ?